# custom State machine design(Chess board)

Tags: java, oop, state-machine

Given a chessboard, If Player move from one position to another, I have to change the game state on some conditions.
So for this, I have come up with my own implementation of the state machine.

```
public enum GameState {
  CREATED,
  IN_PROGRESS,
  BLACK_WIN,
  WHITE_WIN,
  STALEMATE,
  RESIGNATION;

  static Map<GameState, List<GameState>> moveToState = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    moveToState.put(CREATED, Arrays.asList(IN_PROGRESS,RESIGNATION));
    moveToState.put(IN_PROGRESS,Arrays.asList(BLACK_WIN,WHITE_WIN,STALEMATE,RESIGNATION));
    moveToState.put(BLACK_WIN, Collections.emptyList());
    moveToState.put(WHITE_WIN, Collections.emptyList());
    moveToState.put(STALEMATE, Collections.emptyList());
    moveToState.put(RESIGNATION, Collections.emptyList());
  }

  public boolean canMoveToState(GameState fromGameState,GameState toGameState){
    List<GameState> states = moveToState
        .getOrDefault(fromGameState, new ArrayList<>());
    return states.contains(toGameState);
  }
}
```

So my question is this a correct way to implement a state machine, if not what are the possible drawback of this implementation?

Comment: This looks like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @jaco0646 when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_".